# Why is $1 - \cos(x)$ of $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I know the definition of order estimates,

For the solution to apply we need to show:

$ \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x^2} = A \neq 0\space  or \space \infty$

But how can one show this?

Comment: Do taylor expansion about $\cos(x)$, $i.e$  $ \cos(x) = 1- \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots$,

Comment: In this case, we can say $cos(x) = 1 + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$

and then do $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - 1 + \mathcal{O}(x^2)}{x^2} = 1$ ?

Comment: Do you know what $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ means?

Comment: My belief is that it is used to describe some equation. $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ in particular means that the leading terms are $x^2$ when $|x| << 1$

Comment: Using taylor expansion $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2} -\frac{x^2}{4!} + \cdots =\frac{1}{2} + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} O(x^2) = \frac{1}{2}$
This is the same result for below answer by JimmyK4542
which states
$\lim{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \lim{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \frac{1}{1+\cos(x)} = 1 * \frac{1}{2} =\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In other words, the relation of $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$, $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$ is the typical ways to construct the taylor series of certain function. You can find this materials in any Calculus textbook.

Comment: Thanks Phy math, this is what I needed

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If you already know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, then you can use the following: $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \cdot \dfrac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x} = \dfrac{1-\cos^2 x}{x^2(1+\cos x)} = \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{x^2(1+\cos x)} = \left[\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right]^2\dfrac{1}{1+\cos x}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response jimmy!